# Какова философия "диспетчера"?

Tags: python

Замучился сопрягать PHP + Python (в вопросах прав на отдельные системные команды). Решил попробовать реализовать следующую идею: **1**. Зацикливается скрипт диспетчера из-под рута, периодически считывающий инструкции для запуска с некого файла управления запуском. **2** С веба в этот файл записываю инструкцию для запуска "main.py -n gr.1.1" или "main2.py" или "ls -l" **3** Диспетчер вызывает либо системную команду либо другие скрипты, а так как запущен он будет из-под рута, то и проблем не должно быть с "systemctl". Возможно для этой идеи есть уже отработанное решение и название. Буду рад любым советам и подсказкам.

Comment: Потом злоумышленник взламывает ваш сайт и получает полный root-доступ к серверу через этот самый файл. Не надо так делать

Comment: внутренний сайт. Доступ к файлу будет только у вебсервера, на вебе можно сделать аутентификацию. Ну и в Диспетчере фильтр на строго определенный набор команд.

Comment: Держите открытым отдельное окно терминала с правами рута, пока работаете над сайтом. Там и набирайте эти команды.

Comment: Лучше расскажите, какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить таким образом и нахрена вообще дёргать systemctl через сайт

Comment: на питоне есть система Автотеста некого ПАК. Для части тестов у модулей программы меняется конфигурация, которая применяется только при перезапуске модулей. Реализован демон, который запускает модули в определенном порядке с определенными временными интервалами. Вот его и перезапускаю через systemctl. При запуске из консоли все работает, PHP забирает лог и отображает красиво на сайте.